# Any way to change logo on default setup dialogs?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

A default setup project in visual studio 2008 gives you dialogs with a logo-type image in the upper right of a monitor. All I want to do is change this image to new logo. Don't want to deal with custom dialogs. Any way to just change the image?

Comment: [Setup-Dialogs - Own BannerBitmap and SplashBitmap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34086/Setup-Dialogs-Own-BannerBitmap-and-SplashBitmap)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your setup project, go into the User Interface Dialog editor and click on one of the dialogs.  In the properties window for that dialog, you can change the BannerBitmap property to any image that you want.

It's a long thin bitmap that extends across the entire top of the dialog.  The one that I use has about a 7.5:1 width to height ratio.
Specifically, it's a 497x69 pixel bitmap (.bmp).  I don't remember how I came up with that exact size, but it has worked for me.

Comment: I can't find any documentation, what else is new... I screen capture the setup dialog, paste into photoshop and find 621x86 for the banner image. Perhaps this depends on my system font size? I always run large fonts on a high res display. Also see that the bitmap is stretched to fit.

Comment: The correct size is 500x70. Banners of other sizes will be resized (ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kbk77sf.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Please see the this blog post:

http://followtheheard.blogspot.com/2008/09/changing-bitmap-banner-in-visual-studio.html

You can follow Stewbob's way (which is the right way), but it will require you to change the image on every page of every installer you create. The above link will let you change the image in the template that Visual Studio uses to create all of your installer files going forward. That way, you can leave your pages pointing to the Default image, because you changed the Default image to be YOUR image.

This solution worked great for me. Set it and forget it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I changed my Setup Project’s Default Banner Bitmap:-

1. If not already installed, install **Orca**, the MSI File Editor. Orca is part of the Windows SDK Development Kit and, for Windows 10 or 11, its installation file is found at:-
   **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\ Orca-x86_en-us.msi**
2. Run the **Orca** app and open the Setup project’s **.msi** file
3. Under the Edit menu, select the **Find** option (Ctrl-F), and search for ‘**banner**’
4. The **DefBinaryBitmap** item of the **Binary** table will be selected. Double-click on **[Binary Data]** and a dialog box allowing you to select the Setup Project’s default Banner Bitmap is displayed
5. After selecting your bitmap, click Ok, and then Save the .msi file and Exit
6. Note that a Banner Bitmap file can be **.jpg** or **.bmp** files and its size should be **500 x 70** px